# Is it proper to write "In improved contrast"

Tags: phrase-usage

I am comparing the current version of a software product to the previous version, which is not just the contrast, but I am trying to emphasize the improvement.

Does it sound awkward to write "improved contrast" as in:

"So in improved contrast to , the ..."

Comment: I think I would probably say *So in comparison to X, Y offers these improved features*. You may also experiment with using *favourable comparison*. *Improved comparison* does not have a clear idiomatic ring to it - at least not to my ear. But then a awful lot of stuff in technical manuals doesn't!

Comment: In my view - forcing "improved" in front of "contrast" just doesn't sound right. And I am not a native speaker. Are there any restrictions that is preventing you from being expressive? Why not say , *"In contrast to v1.0, v2.0 enhances UX by adding bla bla bla....<insert technical blahs> "*?

Comment: Native speaker here: it sounds totally wrong, and makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, my brain told me no, but my heart was wrestling with it, as in "stark contrast" or "apparent contrast"

Comment: @BiscuitBoy is right. "Improved contrast" makes sense in photography but not here.